# Merging of PySimpleGUI EXE (PyInstaller) icons on the taskbar

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

Windows 10
Python 3.10.2
PySimpleGUI 4.60.5
pyinstaller 3.6.0

Any PySimpleGUI EXEs generated using pyinstaller share the same icon on the taskbar when using PySimpleGUI 4.60.5 (the most recent version). But this issue does not occur with PySimpleGUI 4.57.0 (though it does also happen with the release following 4.57.0 ie 4.58.0)

[Two different EXEs with different names (which would normally have different and separate icons) sharing the same icon on the taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXVUG.png)

Running a third PySimpleGUI 4.60.5 EXE, the same thing happens, and all three share the same icon.

This happens with even the simplest of programs:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.T(f"PSG version: {sg.version}")]]

window = sg.Window('Taskbar icon issue', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

The pyinstaller command takes the form:
`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py --icon icon.ico`
and using earlier versions of pyinstaller do not change anything.

Is this a known issue? I couldn’t find any references to it.

Comment: It's because the EXE on the taskbar is Python.exe.  Right click the icon on the taskbar and choose properties.  The [psgshortcut](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/psgshortcut) application helps with this by creating shortcuts that will be unique.  This works well for PySimpleGUI Python programs.  I'm not sure, however, if it's going to solve this particular problem as each window you create is going to have Python.exe as the taskbar item.  This is a good hint for you to start from though :-)

Comment: I am using Windows Desktop shortcuts, and none of the EXEs are named Python.exe. If this is what you say (which I don't fully understand) why does it not happen with PySimpleGUI 4.57.0?

Comment: Right click your icon on the taskbar.  For the program it shows, right click that and choose properties to get the full info about the EXE.  Open an issue on the PSG GitHub if you want support from the project.  It's a lot easier there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will raise it as an issue.

Comment:  It's difficult to converse without screenshots, etc.  Comments here don't enable the kind of communication needed.  Looking forward to helping....

Comment: Cool. There is a screenshot linked in the question showing two different PySimpleGUI programs running from the same taskbar icon. I had hoped that the screenshot would appear in the main body, but it just appears as a link.

Comment: Open an issue and I'll be happy to help.